# Why is the number of distinct momentum states of a quantum particle moving in one dimension given as $\frac{L_p}{\Delta p_x}\;?$

Tags: quantum-mechanics, statistical-mechanics

I was reading *multiplicity of monatomic gas* where I got to know that it is proportional to the position space & volume space. $$\Omega \propto V\cdot V_p \;. $$

In order to find the constant of proportionality, Daniel Schroeder used uncertainty principle using a one-dimensional example.

[image]

> [...] In this one-dimensional example, the number of distinct position states is $L/(\Delta x)$ while the number of distinct momentum states is $L_p/(\Delta p_x) \;.$ The total number of distinct states is the product $$\frac{L}{\Delta x}\frac{L_p}{\Delta p_x}= \frac{L L_p}{h}\;.$$

But why did the author divide $L$ by $\Delta x$ to calculate the number of distinct position states?

Maybe this is due to the uncertainty in position that if one chooses a certain coordinate, we have to include the uncertainty also. So, that's why $L$ was divided by $\Delta x\; .$ But this is my speculation only; the author didn't tell why he did so.

Could anyone please explain why the number of distinct momentum states is given by $\frac{L_p}{\Delta p_x}\;?$

Also, could anyone tell what these waves are meant for in the above pic taken from the book? I'm not getting those pics:/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The [uncertainty principle](http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/uncer.html), HUP, used in the substitution in the  denominator, is

$$\Delta x\Delta p \gt \frac{\hbar}{2}\\ \Delta E\Delta t \gt \frac{\hbar}{2} $$

where $\Delta x$ and $\Delta p $ are an interval in units of space and momentum respectively, and they define a minimum volume in the combined phase space where the particle can be within the $L$ and the $L_p.$

Since you understand that dividing the length by the uncertainty counts up how many increments exist in space, correspondingly dividing the momentum interval by the uncertainty in momentum can give the number of increments in momentum space. Multiplying the two numbers gives the total number of states, except that they are limited by the HUP in the denominator. It divides the space*momentum area with h units  of area( it should be $\hbar$ over two , but the idea is the same). With the six dimensional volume of ${x,y,z,p_x,p_y,p_z}$ it should be with $h^3.$

> Also, could anyone tell what these waves are meant for in the above pic taken from the book? I'm not getting those pics:/

Think of the particle as a wave packet, i.e. it has a probability distribution in $x$ and a probability distribution in $p.$ Each bump illustrates graphically the probability of the particle's existence , $\Delta x$  and $\Delta p.$

Comment: Okay,why did the author not take the inequality relation of the Uncertainty Principle?

Comment: I made a small edit to this answer to fix two punctuation and grammar typos. I also removed the red coloring and strange font from the math since it made the HUP equations inconsistent with the rest of the answer. Anna, since my rep is high enough my edits do not go to a review, so please just undo the edit if you disagree with it.

Comment: He took the minimum phase space volume. there cannot be more states than the minimum

Comment: @DanielSank thank you Daniel for taking the trouble. As it is practically 15 years since I have been actively writing programs (or papers) mathjax is outside my skills and not useful except here.

Comment: @user36790 "Sorry, master Sank! Don't punish me!!" Huh?

Comment: @user36790  definitey a "she". A grandmother.

Comment: @anna v: Jaws dropped; since my first encounter with you, I've been addressing you as _sir_!! Sorry, really!!

Comment: @DanielSank: You are the king of sock puppets, after all!

Comment: @user36790  Why are you using this antagonistic word, which I had to look up, for the user?  One can never know who is who on the net really, and if there are many identities or not since nothing is forbidden as long as it is within the rules of the site.

Comment: @anna v: Does it matter much? I asked, you answered, I found it answered my question, I accepted, I formatted your answer, you replied to my comments! That's it. What should I want more? After all, _what's in the name? Everything is in the work._- Bhagawad Gita.

Comment: @anna v: If anyone _helps_ me, if anyone _teaches_ me, if anyone _explains_ me, then it is my duty to revere him(her). that's why in order to show respect, I address any user who helps me irrespective of the age, with that word. You helped me, it is my duty to respect you. That's it.

Comment: You misunderstood me. I was not talking of the "sir" that is fine and cute actually :). I was talking of the "sockpuppet" which I had to search for as it was a new word for me.

Comment: @anna v: :P sorry for the philosophical lecture! BTW, if you don't post a comment using `@user`, then he or she wouldn't be pinged; here you posted this comment; I didn't get the notification of it as there is more than one user here you could probably commented to: Sank & me. So, please  put the `@user` whom you want to shew your comment:)